# How do you get the value of a key in Firebase Database and pass it to a TextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering how I can find the value of a key in my JSON database using Objective C and pass it to a textfield. I want to collect data from the 3rd key in my database (Excluding the title node, of course) but every explanation on how to just doesn't seem to work. The code for traversing to the right location is:

```
FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;
NSString* username = _usernameEntry.text;
if (user)
{
    [[[[_ref child: @"Users"] child:user.uid] child:@"Username"]observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot)
    {
        User *username = [[User alloc] initWithUsername:snapshot.value[@"username"]];
    }
    withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];

    _emailAddressEntry.text = user.email;
}
```

for me. My intention is for the username text field to show the current username, when the view controller is navigated to. This is so that the user can see what it is now and edit it, if anything was misstyped/isn't to their satisfaction (Similarly to how it's done with the email text field).

Side Note, the username and email are stored/modified like this:

```
NSString *userID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;
NSString* username = _usernameEntry.text;

[[[_ref child:@"Users"] child:userID] setValue:@{@"Username": username}];

[[FIRAuth auth].currentUser updateEmail:_emailAddressEntry.text
                             completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
 {
     if(error)
     {
         [_emailValidationCheck setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
         _emailValidationCheck.text = @"Email Address modification was unsuccessful";
     }
     else
     {
         [_emailValidationCheck setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
         _emailValidationCheck.text = @"Email Address modification was successful";
     }
 }];
}
```

Additionally, I have a question about two additional things. 1) Why does the userID key always get overwritten in this traversal? I define it as having the name User_ID and the value of uid in the registration view controller, however when people edit their username on the profile page in my application, it gets overwritten and turned into just the key. Before this, it was being turned into just the name (No value).

Comment: Are you asking how to [Read Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) from Firebase? It's covered in that document; ObjC and Swift. In general, please include a snippet of your Firebase structure and what code you've tried so we can understand your use case (as TEXT please, no images). Also, please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. I've already tried using the documentation, it yields no useful results.

Comment: Your code sets up a reference to a node in the database. What's the problem you're having with it?

Comment: As a side note, there really aren't *3rd nodes* in Firebase; nodes are key: value pairs and are generally read via the node name (key). While there are arrays available (with numerical indexes), they should be avoided.

Comment: Your code appears to overwrite the username as it's defined once as _usernameEntry.text and then overwritten by the username = [[[ line. How are you storing the username in Firebase? Perhaps including your structure would help us understand what your use case as it's a bit unclear from the code.

Comment: The problem I'm having is I can't read the data stored on it, when I implement their code it simply doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't overwrite the username, as my implementation of the actual database modification code is attached to the action of pressing the "Apply Changes" button. This should only display the current username in the username box, it was MUCH easier for the email address since that's not stored in the same database as this stuff.

Comment: Also, while we're at it, I also had an issue with this traversal, not so long ago. If I were to type in just the name of the location in the database, so for User_ID that would be @"User_ID", it would overwrite that location and remove the value it had, so that it was only known by the name, which I thought was strange, as I was stepping over that to place something underneath it.

Comment: Also, thank you for pointing that out, username and the usernameTextEntry are in the wrong positions, that should be inverted.

Comment: Any help? I kinda need urgent support...

Comment: Well, you've not implemented (all of) their code. For example, there's no code in your question that actually *reads data from Firebase*. To read data you would need to implement either *observe* or *observeSingleEventOfType* per the documentation.

Comment: I did that, it doesn't work. "            User *username = [[User alloc] initWithUsername:snapshot.value[@"username"]];" doesn't work at all...

Comment: Any help with that?

Comment: The code in your question does not contain any calls to read from the database as far as I can see. As Jay said, reading from the database is done with `observe...`, such as those shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events .

Comment: Listen, I'm telling you guys that I've tried implanting that code, but it just doesn't work at all because of that 1 line that uses a data type that is nonexistent

Comment: Also, the code in the post that you flagged as an "Exact duplicate" did contain the method you spoke about.

Comment: I've copied and pasted the contents of the newer post onto this post, now, is that better? I need quicker responses, not to nag.

Comment: Look, I understand that you don't have all the time in the world and might not possess the knowledge to help me, but you could've at least not flagged the newer post. Like I said, I'm inching closer and closer to my deadline, all this did was possibly delay it even more. The newer post had a much more concise title that may have attracted people who could help me, quickly.

Comment: Ah, so adding the observeSingleEvent read the data from Firebase. Very good! Please remember we are *volunteers* and do this to *help others* (for free). Becoming aggravated and demanding quicker responses because you are on a deadline will likely get you removed from this site. Please be kind and thoughtful when posting and commenting. Remember to update you own posts with new an updated information instead of creating another which is similar.

Comment: Yes, I'm very well aware of that, frustration leads to abnormal responses, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

if (user)
{
    [[[[_ref child: @"Users"] child:user.uid] child:@"Username"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
    {
        if (snapshot.exists)
        {
            _usernameEntry.text = snapshot.value;
        }
    }];

    _emailAddressEntry.text = user.email;
}
```

Was the solution I made to my problem.

Comment: You may or may not be aware but the *_emailAddressEntry* line of code will execute way before the Firebase block does due to it being asynchronous. If may not affect your code as we don't know the whole use case but if you run into issues in the future - that may be part of it. It could be better to include that inside the block so the populate at the same time.